Safari doesn't hide elements with display:none after injecting them
I use the JS library MagnificPopup to display popups on my website when the user clicks on a "read more" button. MagnificPopup apparently takes my html, displays it at a different location and on close, it injects the html back to where it was. This works perfectly fine in all major browsers except for Safari.
For some reason, when the popup closes and the html is inejcted back to where it was, Safari doesn't hide the element properly even though I believe it should. The sorounding elemnt has display:none and I even tried to set width, height, padding and margin all to 0 but it doesn't work.
As soon as the window is resized, the element is hidden again but unless the window is resized, the layout is messed up.
This is the layout before:

And this is the layout after clicking the read more button and closing the popup:

You can see the problem here: https://demo.divi-pixel.com/creative/testimonials/
Can anybody explain why this is happening and why it's happening in Safari only? Does anybody have a workaround for this?

Have you tried reporting this to the developer? Although it looks like they've abandoned it, the last release was 8 years ago.

Have you tried visibility:hidden together with display:none?
Some browsers do not render well elements as hidden only with display:none, and keep 'virtual' space for the element instead. Including both directives should work just about always and everywhere.

Doesn't work either. :(

@xxtesaxx I'm not able to reproduce the error. Could you specify OS/Browser/Version used?

@xxtesaxx I suspect this happens on Safari because it handles somewhat differently the application of certain CSS directives. This applies mainly to positioning and dimensioning of elements. You included a snapshot with only some of the CSS settings of the element in the moment of the problem. Could you include a full list? I'm almost certain the catch will show up somewhere in there.

It might be some super weird behavior caused by the JS libraries involved. The original element is part of a SwiperJS carousel and MagnificPopup takes the elements content out of there to display it, then injects it back once the popup is closed.
I found a workaround though. Instead of having the elements, which MP uses, as a top level element in the carousel, I found that when I nest them inside a div, then the issue is gone because the then top level div doesn't get modified by MP.
After all its probably nothing I could fix otherwise.

I'd have liked to have the elements for the popups not to be part of the carousel at all but that is a limitation due to project constraints. but wrapping inside a div is an acceptable workaround in this case.
